# Use python to download picture on Android Phone

Tags: python, android

I tried to use Python to download a picture to a phone

Here's the code I used:

```
import urllib.request
import os 
  
src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/10/dc/7110dce004b8f7d45c0308217f935ad7.png'
 
os.chdir('/storage/emulated/0/Download/')

urllib.request.urlretrieve(src , '0.png')
```

It downloaded successfully to my [downloads folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etWfw.jpg), but I can't see it in my photo album. Then I tried to renaming the picture. Surprisingly, it appears in the photo album now. I also tried to move or replace it. It all appears in photo album.

It seems that the picture can't be recognized by phone at first

It needs to do a move or rename or replace, but it is impractical to manually go through all the pictures and rename them. Is there any way to do the renaming programmatically (I tried `os.rename()`)? And why do I have to rename in the first place?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What are you trying to achieve? It seems you are just telling us a story. What do you need help with?

Comment: The problem is that i can't see it in photo album after downloaded

Comment: But you seemed to have solved that by renaming/moving.

Comment: But if i have 1000 pictures , i will need to do it 1000 times

Comment: Okay, now I think get it. You want to automate it/not have to rename?

Comment: Yes, also i have tried os.rename but still not work

Comment: Do you think the edit makes that a little clearer?